# Error: Could not find or load main class intellij Idea

Tags: java, main

Программа выдает такую ошибку при запуске.
Прописал в командоре класспас

```
C:\Users\yuri>cd\

C:\>set path="C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171\bin"

C:\>set classpath="C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_171\lib\rt.jar"

C:\>
```

скриншот с программой приложил.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

в чем проблема?

Comment: Вы должны указать явно класс запуска: `java -cp App.jar Display.class`. Системные переменные тут не при чем.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By [Tsyklop](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/208500/tsyklop):

> Вы должны указать явно класс запуска: `java -cp App.jar Display.class`.
>   Системные переменные тут не при чем.

Если это не помогло, то вот еще способы(из [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10654120/error-could-not-find-or-load-main-class-in-intellij-ide) на enSO):

1) <kbd>Build</kbd> → <kbd>Rebuild Project</kbd>. Иногда Intellij не переписывает классы, потому что они уже существуют, таким образом вы просите Intellij переписать все.

2)<kbd>Run</kbd> → <kbd>Edit configuration</kbd> → удалить профиль → добавить профиль ("Application" если это Java приложение), выберите основной класс из раскрывающегося меню «Main class».

3)<kbd>Build</kbd> → <kbd>Rebuild Project</kbd>.

Еще способ -
Закройте свою IDE IntelliJ и удалите файл и папку(.idea) IntelliJ IDE из корня проекта: